# Navbar interfering with headers HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, nav

I'm trying to create a navbar with a logo within it. I have the navbar basically working, but the headers for page content is being forced into the navbar as well. [image]

Here is my HTML and a link to my website for full source and viewing (http://frankkreutzer.com/)

```
        <header class="section">
        <a id="logo" href="http://frankkreutzer.com"><img src="images/logo.png" width="75" height="75"></a>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://frankkreutzer.com" id="current">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://frankkreutzer.com/it-130/assignment-3/assignment3.html" target="_blank">IT 130</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://frankkreutzer.com/csgo/csgo-home.html" target="_blank">CS:GO Project</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://frankkreutzer.com/cth-247/index.html" target="_blank">CTH Final Project</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://frankkreutzer.com/contact.html">Contact Me</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Here is some of my CSS:

```
header {
top: 0;
right: 0;
left: 0;
border-bottom: 1px solid #e3e3e8;
}

#logo {
    float: left;
    font-size: 3em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: .4em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #222222;
    transition: .5s all;
}

nav {
    float: right;
}

nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2.8em 2em;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 .4em;
}

nav ul li a {
    color: #222222;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-bottom: .5em;
    transition: .5s color;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #222222;
}

#current {
    color: #ff4629;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #222222;
}
```

Comment: `.content {clear: both;}`     -- more here: https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/#article-header-id-2

Comment: since you are using float properties on the divs. You can either use .content{clear:both } or header{ width:100%; float:left;}

Comment: @ovokuro uhhh, what and how did that just work?

Comment: Thank you both, and thanks @ovokuro for the article!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add overflow property in header.

```
header{overflow: hidden;}
```